# How many possible values the periode of a pseudo random generator can have?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

As an example: $$x_{n+1}=(3x_n+b)\quad  mod\quad  20 \quad (1)$$
Here we can choose b and $x_0$ arbitrarily. Instead I wrote an equivalent form of the above equation:$$3x_n+b\equiv x_{n+1}\pmod {20} \quad (2)$$

The solution to the second equation I find as: $$x_n = 7(x_{n+1}-b)\quad mod\quad20 \quad (3)$$.

Further to find the periode i take the first $x_{n+1}$ which is equal to $x_0$:
$$x_{n+1} = x_0 = (3x_n+b) \quad mod \quad 20 \quad (4)$$

I substitute equation (3) in equation (4) and find:

$$x_0 = (((x_0-b) \quad mod \quad 20) \quad +b) mod \quad 20$$.

I got stuck here. My plan is to solve the last equation for $x_0$ and conclude something.

I already tried to gain some idea via coding it in python, so far i only found only twee different periode for this problem, nl. 2 and 4.

I ain't quite sure if my strategy gonna work or maybe I'm in wrong path.

Comment: Note that in your last equation, the $21$ becomes $1$ as you are working modulo $20$. Your equation is therefore $x_0 = ((x_0 - b) \pmod {20}) + b \pmod {20}$. I don't think you can get a lot from there.

Comment: @F.Carette thank you i edited it, so i appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: I don't have time to post an answer right now, but I found a max period of 4. Try expressing $x_{n+k}$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$. I'll post an answer later if you didn't find it.

Comment: $x_1 = 3x_0 + b$, $x_2 = 3(3x_0 + b) + b = 9x_0 + 4b$, $x_3 = 3(9x_0 + 4b) + b = 7x_0 + 13b$, $x_4 = 3(7x_0 + 13b) + b = 21x_0 + 40b = x_0$. This proves that the period is at most 4